# Dropdown textbox design in css

Tags: html, css, textbox, dropbox

I want create a dropdown box like bootstrap. Even I created it, but actually I need it in simple css. Because when I use bootstrap file on my page then all formates becomes wrong due to I never added any code related bootstrap on my website.

Below the image I want to create. 
[image]

Below is my code I used un bootstrap and it bit looks like above image. But I don't know  how I made this in css.

Please anyone help me, how I make the dropdown textbox in css without bootstrap like above image.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>



<div class="form-group col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
  <label>Title</label>
  <select id="txtTitle" class="form-control selectpicker">
        <option value="default">Please Select</option>
        <option value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two">Two</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
  <label>Choose Activities</label>
  <select id="DDLActivites" data-style="btn-default" class="selectpicker form-control" multiple data-max-options="2">
        <option>Mustard</option>
        <option>Barbecue</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 (quick) options:

1. Chosen: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/
2. select2: https://select2.org/

Both look exactly the same as the bootstrap version and offer the same functionality without messing with your themes styles.

Comment: thank u for reply, but I believe there is not the answer actually I want . It's not show same as my image. You have knowledge then why you not share with us. It will increase nit decrease if share. I thought.. nit only you anyone who watch this post or comments this..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this sample using select2.  Straight from the select2 web site.

http://jsfiddle.net/r0yh3b4o/1/

```
 <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state" style="width:100%">
   <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
   <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
  </select>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
    });
```

Comment: I seen in jsfiddle it works good. But when I use this code on my site , nothing changes even I use cdn file available on select2.org. why?  I used Js and Css file , but not works even I  use the class name your uses. But not works.